# Shell Regex not matching

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I need to extract the version from a line in shell scrip but my regex is not picking up the correct value.

this is my script:

```
versionLine="Creating version 1.0.74 ++ grep 'Creating version ' /tmp/apps/runtime/data/jenkins/jobs/myJob/build/68/log"
re=".*Creating version (.*) \+\+.*"

if [[ ${versionLine} =~ $re ]]
then
        echo FOUND: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Code does not go inside the `if`. I would like to echo: `FOUND: 1.0.74`

Comment: Strange. It works for me...

Comment: BTW, the leading and trailing `.*` are implicit. You don't need them.

Comment: Anyhow -- the code you gave here *works*, if run as bash as the shell. (If you ran it with `sh`, not so much). Can you show us exactly how it's invoked, what errors are emitted, etc?

Comment: And in the future, make sure you're providing a [mcve] -- part of the "verifiable" part of that is someone else should see the bug themselves if they copy-and-paste what you provided.

Comment: Thanks for including a MCVE and explaining the expected behavior! Can you also include the *actual* behavior, i.e. how you run it and what the output is?

Comment: @thatotherguy, I disagree: This isn't a MCVE, since nobody else can actually verify it. If it *actually* produced the bug when run, *then* it would be a MCVE.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/xNnTnL -- the "stdout" section shows "FOUND" being emitted on output when the exact code given by the OP in this question is run.

Comment: @ATorre, consider using `printf 'versionLine=%q\n' "$versionLine"` to emit a command which, when run, will set `versionLine` to the *actual* value you have at runtime. (By contrast, if you get an error saying the format string is invalid, that tells us that the shell isn't either bash or ksh, which means it likely doesn't have built-in regex support at all).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm able to reproduce the problem with this exact snippet in a non-`bash` tagged question, so I'd argue that that it's a MCVE -- it's just missing invocation.

Comment: @thatotherguy, if it's missing invocation instructions necessary to produce the behavior at hand, it's not complete enough to be verifiable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is reproducible with `chmod +x myfile && ./myfile` which is how you always run shell scripts. It's just not reproducible from a bash shell or if `sh` is `bash`

Comment: @thatotherguy, depends on which shell one uses when running `./myfile`, if there's no shebang. Which is to say, there are still undefined factors required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script uses bash-only syntax, but does not have a shebang.

Add to the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

(or `#!/bin/bash`, as appropriate)

...and ensure that you don't invoke it with `sh yourscript`.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy! that was the problem!

Comment: That being the case, there would have been an error printed up stderr when the script tried to run. In the future, please include such errors in your question.